# Difference between numpy.argmax(array) and array.argmax() in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am asking a very basic question but I am a new python programmer and couldn't find the answer.

Question: What is the difference between **"numpy.argmax(array)"** and **"array.argmax()"** ? However, they both give the same result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: It is common in `numpy` that both variants work, like `numpy.sum(arr)` and `arr.sum()`. I personally would prefer numpy.fun(), because this also works for scalars and list, while `[1, 2, 3].sum()` fails

Comment: Where does the `array.argmax()` function come from? Is it a method of the builtin [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference, `array.argmax` is just the method implemented on the `array` object, whereas `numpy.argmax` is the method implemented as a standalone function that can be passed any array-like object, e.g. a Python list.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> a.argmax()
2

>>> np.argmax([1,2,3])
2
```